# How do model data in Cassandra for faster reads?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

We have modeled data in Cassandra. There is continuous write that happens on data because of events generated by different systems. The schema of the table is defined below. The WRITE works fine on the table but READ with where clause of id takes up to 9s on 99th percentile. Kindly help me with better design of this table. The data column contains a JSON string up to 2KB.

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    id text,
    p1 text,
    o1 text,
    s1 text,
    data text,
    enabled boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, p1, o1, s1)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (p1 ASC, o1 ASC, s1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX table_enabled_idx ON table (enabled);
```

Comment: Can you mention your read queries which take the most time? Also good that you have mentioned the "data" column size, but can you also estimate how many rows will be present for a particular "id" key. We can use that to see a partition size.

Comment: Right now the number of rows is close to 1.6 Million.

This is how the query looks like. This is the only query with a different value of id is being fired.
select * from table where id = '961:3387:2019-06-30';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table_enabled_idx` index will be very slow and eventually break. ditch it.

LeveledCompactionStrategy will flat out improve read performance. STCS only better if you never read the data or on ancient disks imho. Set `dclocal_read_repair_chance` to zero (wont really make a difference but might as well).

Need a trace to identify if its something else like being too wide, too many tombstones etc which what you provided doesnt tell. Can also be GCs from unrelated things like compactions, bad jvm settings, other data models on system etc. Enable speculative execution on driver to work around GCs if they are infrequent.

Comment: Good call on getting rid of the index.  Secondary indexes on extremely low cardinality columns will get wide fast, and eventually be useless.

Comment: I could imagine that your selection of partition key leads to huge partitions. But just a guess. Can you provide the output of nodetool tablehistograms <keyspace> <table> ?